# Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Hide "Unsubscribe" button for Transactional Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to hide the "Unsubscribe" button from my Transactional emails.  We are currently using the out of the box "Headers and Footers" that appear in Setup > Account Settings.

I would like to still have the "Unsubscribe" button appear for Commercial/Marketing emails.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a support ticket to request to disable the CAN-SPAM requirements. This makes it so the `%%unsub_center_url%%` and `%%profile_center_url%%` links are not required when validating/sending an email.

With this disabled, you do have to remember to adhere to CAN-SPAM laws by putting unsubscribe links in your Commercial messages. You can do this either in your Headers and Footers as you mentioned and also Sender Profiles.